# Is T... (generics vararg parameter) really stripped down to Object[] at compile time?

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions

(I'll use T to refer to a generic argument here, used in a parameterized class.)

I read that the reason that `T...` is a potential source of heap pollution when used as an argument is that the compiler is making an exception to the normal (no `T[]` arrays allowed) rule, and allowing `T...` (which is varargs, and so would normally translate by varargs rules internally to `T[]`, except that this isn't allowed with generics) as a parameter by implementing it internally as though it were a raw type, converting it to an array of `Object[]` instead.

So I wrote some code to verify this, to cement the concept into my memory.

I took `T...t` as an argument to a method, and then `System.out.println`'d `t.getClass[]`.  I expected to get the class of `Object[]`, but instead, I got `T[]`'s class.

So, it appears that the compiler is converting `T...t` to `T[]` internally, and not to `Object[]`.

e.g.

```
 public class MyClass<T>{
 public void method(T...t)
 {
    System.out.println(t.getClass().getName());  //for MyClass<String>, this gives me  
                                                 //[Ljava.lang.String

 }
```

What am I missing here?  And if the compiler's not converting the generic varargs parameter internally to `Object[]`, how is it losing type safety and acting as a potential source of heap pollution?

Comment: how did you call the method? `method("string", "another");`?

Comment: Yes. 

MyClass<String> mc = new MyClass<String>();
mc.method("what","the","something");

Comment: If you remove the type annotation (just `MyClass mc`) will it become `Object[]` then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
void method(T... t)
```

gets converted to

```
void method(Object[] t)
```

so what you have heard is correct. *But*:

```
Integer a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
method(a, b, c);
```

gets converted into:

```
Integer a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
method(new Integer[] {a, b, c});
```

so the runtime type of `t` is `Integer[]`, even though its declared type (after compilation) is `Object[]`.

Comment: I suppose the component type is taken from the generic type annotation by the compiler? Or is it inferred from the actual arguments?

Comment: Thank you!

Though, if the compiled type is void method(Object[] t),
why does the compiler still reject the method call

     MyClass<String> mc = new MyClass<String>();   
     mc.method("what","the","something",4);

With compiler message: "The method method(String...) in the type GenericsReview<String> is not applicable for the arguments 
 (String, String, String, int)"

(The rejection of int isn't an autoboxing failure, since 
mc.method("what","the","something",new Integer(4)); is also rejected.)

Comment: @Thilo I would guess (I don't know for certain) that it's inferred from the actual arguments. Maybe try replacing `T` with `Object` and see if `t instanceof Integer[]` is true.

Comment: @Mer generics are discarded *after compiling*, because the JVM doesn't need to care about them. That doesn't mean they don't do anything. In particular, the compiler checks that you didn't mess up the generics.

Comment: So, then, how is this losing type safety and becoming a potential heap pollution source (It does generate heap pollution warnings.) if it's maintaining the type safety protections offered by generics?

Comment: Or does that tie back to the fact that you ultimately end up with an array, which is by nature, not type safe since it can be upcast to an array of its supertype?

Comment: @Kayaman that can't be a sufficient explanation, because then a `List<String>` would also "lose type safety".

Comment: @Kayaman Try it. The example in this answer is correct, it becomes `Integer[]`.

Comment: @Mer: Imagine you have a method that takes `T... args` (`args` has type `T[]`) and simply returns `args`, as type `T[]`. Now by passing to this varargs function and getting the result, you have accomplished `new T[...]`, which is not allowed in Java. If you understand why `new T[...]` is not allowed, and why you cannot safely replace it with `(T[])new Object[...]`, you will understand why this is unsafe.